# How to select from a table with condition from json column?

Tags: json, postgresql

I have a table `contact_information` at PostreSQL 9.6.

```
CREATE TABLE contact_information
(
  employee_id UUID NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  messengers JSON NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO contact_information 
  (employee_id, messengers) 
VALUES 
  ('8b5fbfec-d213-426c-86fa-4fda5f586319', '[{"Type":"skype","IDs":["some skype id","another skype id"]}]');
```

I need to select all employee_id where IDs contains substring, for example, "id ILIKE '%other%'".

What have I tried:

```
SELECT
  ci.employee_id,
  json_array_elements(json_array_elements(ci.messangers)->'IDs'::text)::text AS ids
FROM contact_information AS ci
```

and got:

```
3ba6feba-ff81-11e4-9408-984be16afda1    "some skype id"
3ba6feba-ff81-11e4-9408-984be16afda1    "another skype id"
```

But I can't to add to statement WHERE ids ILIKE '%other%' - column ids is not exists.

If I'm trying

```
SELECT
  ci.employee_id
FROM contact_information AS ci
WHERE json_array_elements(json_array_elements(ci.messangers)->'IDs'::text)::text ILIKE '%other%'
```

got: ERROR: set-returning functions are not allowed in WHERE.

Any ideas to solve that problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.employee_id 
FROM (
  SELECT
    ci.employee_id,
    json_array_elements(json_array_elements(ci.messangers)->'IDs'::text)::text AS ids
  FROM contact_information AS ci
) as t
WHERE t.ids ILIKE '%other%'
```

Sorry for a silly question =(